# Choosing test to compare biological measurements at three timepoints

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

In my study design, I'm measuring concentrations of different mediators at an acute event (time 1) and at two follow-up timepoints (time 2 and time 3). My main question is whether the concentrations are higher during the acute event (time 1) than time 2 or 3.

I was doing paired T-tests on 1 vs. 3, 2 vs. 3 and 1 vs. 2, but I realize that it's probably incorrect, as it doesn't correct for multiple testing, right? Also, I would like to be able to control for possible confounders (covariates).

My question is, which test should I choose? Repeated measures ANOVA or a mixed model? Or something else? I don't have much experience with this type of statistical analysis, so a detailed answer would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are measuring the **same** experimental unit ([repeated measures design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design)) over more than 2 time points, you definitely want to choose something other than paired t-tests. A repeated measures ANOVA, or a linear mixed-effects model containing random and fixed effects, can both be used for that. Have a look here on CV using the search box on the top right. There is a multitude of good answers on this topic. Then if something is unclear, rephrase your question, provide your data structure and the software you are planning to use.